# Getting access to a different domain from an EXE created in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cross-domain, sandbox

I have create a Flash EXE in AS3. At the time of launch the exe loads a XML from a web link to validate itself.

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://abc.com:8090/validate.xml");
var urlLoader:Loader = new Loader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, startLoad);
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

I have also place a crossdomain.xml at the root. When I launch the EXE, the debugger shows "SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context."

Please help...

I just found a strange thing that when I'm writing the code on the timeline, its working (no security errors). But when I'm writing this code in the document class its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas:

1. It could be your xml path is wrong (why port 8090?)
2. When you say you put the crossdomain.xml at the "root" do you mean the root of abc.com? ('cause that's where it needs to go)
3. Can you post your crossdomain.xml? in order to work locally as an EXE I'm guessing it needs:

   <allow-access-from domain="*" />

Comment: Yes, I have done all the steps that you're telling, but still getting the problem. The actual path is [THIS](http://license.attanocorp.com:8090/DemoCMS/TimeCheckServlet?serial_no=111)

Comment: I clicked that link and I don't see an XML file. I just see "INACTIVE".  This is an old question though, so I hope you figured it out!